Where does Frontiers submission (https://www.frontiersin.org/submission) save the submission draft data, local or server?
I am using my account to submit a manuscript and fill the platform submission content and save it in the Frontiers submission platform, here is the submission filling status picture (as picture A).
But the submission draft is lost after closing the browser and logging in again. All my work on filling in the data was completely wasted! What is the reason for this and how can I avoid it?
Where does the Frontiers submission platform store the submission draft data, locally or on the server? If on the server, why did my draft disappear?
Picture A: submit status



